# Adding functions to my Google app engine app made with Java and JDO

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

Here is my testing app: http://caoscoding.appspot.com

login: admin
pass: test

Is an simple app where you insert some data and get out a table, of that data, that's all.

I want to add 2 more functions: modify an entry and delete an entry.

How should I write these 2 functions? I don't have any good idea any more..

The orm is JDO, and is all made with java.

Please suggest any idea to do so, or any code snippet. I don't know how to edit, save and put the updated entry in the datastore. And don't know how to delete it either, I am really stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

To edit an entry you would do something like:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
// some query to retrieve your object/entry
...
// then make the changes you want to your object
....
// then write it back as per below:
pm.makePersistent(myObject);
```

The call to the persistence manager to delete an entry would similarly be:

```
pm.deletePersistent(myObject);
```

Comment: except that when you call update on a field of your object it is already managed at that point so there is no need for "makePersistent"

Comment: hmm the function that I implemented works like this: you insert the data in the form and when you push the button it calls a put.java where I get the input of the form like this  String var_des =request.getParameter("description"); than I create my JDO object open PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager(); and put inside the datastore my JDO object. I don't know how connect/implement the front end where the user select the data that wont to delete or modify. This is where I am stucked. Don't know how to query the things to be deleted or modfied. I need here some idea.

Comment: This is exatly what I don't know how to do it:                    // some query to retrieve your object/entry
...
// then make the changes you want to your object
....
// then write it back as per below: